# xlsxwriter add a macro on "thisworkbook" to execute on opening

Tags: excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have extracted the bin file from a XMLS where the code is in Thisworkbook because I need to run the macro on opening of the file
I am not able to create with the following code an XLSM which execute the code on opening: XLSM created has "Thisworkbook" and "Thisworkbook1" and the code is not running on opening

```
import xlsxwriter


strn =" Feb "
## Region Level

Loc = Location.reset_index()


for n, g in Matrix.groupby('Cluster'):

    out_path = "D:/Actions/Results/Action-Opp "  + n.strip(" ") +  strn + ".xlsx" 
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path , engine='xlsxwriter')

    C =Loc[Loc.Cluster==n].iloc[:,1:]
    B =SPs[SPs.Cluster==n]
    D = PDet[PDet.Cluster==n]
    F = OppD[OppD.Cluster==n]

    Total.iloc[:,:-2].to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Region",   index=True) 
    C.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Stores", index=False)
    B.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="SPs", index=False)
    D.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Portfolio Details",   index=False)

    F.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Opportunity Details",  index=False)

    workbook  = writer.book
    workbook.filename = "D:/Actions/Results/Action-Opp "  + n.strip(" ") +  strn + ".xlsm" 
    worksheet1 = writer.sheets['Region']
    worksheet2 = writer.sheets['Stores']
    worksheet3 = writer.sheets['SPs']
    workbook.set_vba_name('Stores')
    workbook.add_vba_project('D:/Actions/vbaProject.bin')

    writer.save()


elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print(elapsed)
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Working with VBA Macros - What to do if it doesn’t work](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html#what-to-do-if-it-doesn-t-work) section of the XlsxWriter docs. There are some debugging steps there that you can try.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to create an xlsm file which will contain a macro that will run automatically every time you open the workbook (as long as the file's folder is set as trusted location):

1) Create an excel file, insert a new module and type this vba code:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Save the file as xlsm.

2) Extract the vba code using xlsxwriter's vba_extract.py utility.

3) Run the following python script:

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
workbook.filename = 'test.xlsm'
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Inject the bin file we extracted earlier
workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')

# Finally write the file
workbook.close()
```

This will create a file with the macro injected into it and automatically running every time you open it.

Output:
[image]

If you are still having problems i would recommend you to check 2 things: Firstly if your macro starts with the keyword `Sub Auto_Open()` and secondly if you have set the folder where you open the file as trusted location (because by default office apps will block any macros from running in case they contain malicious code).